# check for only on child object should have data

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have below class object structure with having three inner objects and i am trying to check that only one child object should have the data other wise throw an error and i can do this with if- else statements but looking to see any other way to implement this

```
public class GlazingOrGasMaterial
{
    public GlazingComplexMaterial GlazingComplexMaterial { get; set; }
    public GlazingSimpleMaterial GlazingSimpleMaterial { get; set; }
    public GlazingGasMaterial GlazingGasMaterial { get; set; }

    public GlazingOrGasMaterial(GlazingOrGasMaterial layer)
    {
        if (layer.GlazingComplexMaterial != null && layer.GlazingGasMaterial != null && layer.GlazingSimpleMaterial == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("exception for more than one object having  data");
        }
        // more if statements
    }
}
```

and i am calling this constructor like as in below

```
        foreach(var layer in input.Layers)
        {
            GlazingOrGasMaterial glazingOrGasMaterial = new GlazingOrGasMaterial(layer);
        }
```

Could any one please let me know any way to do this escaping bunch of if-else statements, many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a collection from your objects and counting the ones which meet your expectation:

```
public GlazingOrGasMaterial(GlazingOrGasMaterial layer)
{
    if (new object[] { layer.GlazingComplexMaterial, layer.GlazingSimpleMaterial, layer.GlazingGasMaterial }.Count(x => x != null) != 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Expected only one material");
    }

    ...
}
```

I think you could also consider using a different data modeling approach to enforce this requirement - for example, you could make all of the materials inherit from abstract BaseMaterial and then have the "container" class (if you'd still need it) with only one BaseMaterial property instead of 3 separate ones.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, according OOP, other guys are right, you had better change your class strategy. But I don't know the whole task so I'm able to give an advice only.
I also provided another solution of your question according to your requirements:

```
public GlazingOrGasMaterial(GlazingOrGasMaterial layer)
{
    BitArray materialBits = new BitArray(new bool[] { layer.GlazingComplexMaterial != null, layer.GlazingGasMaterial != null, layer.GlazingSimpleMaterial != null });
    byte[] array = new byte[1]; // max number of states depends on the type: byte - 8, short - 16 etc.
    materialBits.CopyTo (array, 0);
    byte materialState = array[0];
    if((materialState != 0) && ((materialState & (materialState - 1)) == 0)) //check if only 1 property has a data
        throw new ArgumentException("exception for more than one object having  data");
    else
        //do what you wish
        //an example, using by switch you could recognize the exactly not null property
}
```

Comment: thanks, but do not want to go bit deep where we can use bit array

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the shape of your class to enforce the 1 material rule. If all the possible materials extend from a common material, then you can create this base class and only allow one instance.

```
public class GlazingOrGasMaterial
{
    public Material _material { get; set; }

    public GlazingOrGasMaterial(Material material)
    {
        _material = material;       
    }
}   
public class Material
{       
}   
public class GlazingComplexMaterial : Material
{       
}   
public class GlazingSimpleMaterial : Material
{       
}   
public class GlazingGasMaterial : Material
{       
}
```

You can then instantiate the class with one of the materials without having to worry that there are multiple. This avoids runtime exceptions!

```
void Main()
{
    var material = new GlazingComplexMaterial();
    
    new GlazingOrGasMaterial(material); 
}
```

This also avoids the problem in the original design where a 2nd or even 3rd material can just be assigned, without going through the constructor validation logic.